# The like of a user is being shown when the user removed their like in my program. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

To explain what I mean in the title, let me show you the output.

This is the like button counter when the user did not click on the like button:

[image]

This is the like button counter when the user clicked on the like button:

[image]

This is the like button counter when the user clicked on the like button again to remove their like:

[image]

The program I wrote seems to be kind of messed up. Here it is:
This is the route info for this particular page:

```
@app.route('/postlikes/<string:post_name>', methods=["GET","POST"])
def postlikes(post_name):
    if request.method == "POST":
        JSONdata = request.json
        posts = Image.query.filter_by(post_name=post_name)
        if JSONdata['is_liked'] == True:
            for post in posts:
                post.likes += 1
                db.session.commit()
        elif JSONdata['removed_like'] == True:
            for post in posts:
                post.likes = post.likes
                db.session.commit()
    else:
        post = Image.query.filter_by(post_name=post_name).first()
        return {"post_likes":post.likes}
            
        
@app.route('/hasliked/<string:post_name>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def hasliked(post_name):
    post = Image.query.filter_by(post_name=post_name).first()
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first()
    is_liked = posts_liked_by_users.query.filter_by(post_name=post_name).first()
    if is_liked.post_name == post.post_name and is_liked.user_id == user.id:
        return {"has_liked":True}
    else:
        return {"has_liked":False}
```

This is the JS involved in the program:

```
            <script>
                const likebtn = document.getElementById('likebtn');
                const currentURL = window.location.href;
                const likenum = document.getElementById('likenumber');
                const postarray = currentURL.split("/");
                const postName = postarray[4];

                function setLikeBtnColor() {
                    likebtn.style.color = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('likebtn')) ? 'cornflowerblue':'black';
                }
            
                setLikeBtnColor();

                async function current_color() {
                    const fetchData = await fetch('/hasliked/'+postName)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(function newdata(data) {
                        let strdata = JSON.stringify(data)
                        let JSONdata = JSON.parse(strdata)
                        return JSONdata

                    })
                    return fetchData

                }

                async function set_color() {
                    const jsondata = await current_color()
                    if (jsondata['has_liked'] === true) {
                        likebtn.style.color = 'cornflowerblue'

                    } else {
                        likebtn.style.color = 'black'

                    }

        
                }
                

                async function getLikeNumber() {
                    const fetchData = await fetch('/postlikes/'+postName)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(function getdata(data) {
                        let strdata = JSON.stringify(data)
                        let JSONdata = JSON.parse(strdata)
                        likenum.textContent = JSONdata.post_likes
                        return JSONdata.post_likes
                    })
                    return fetchData
                }

                async function displayLikes() {
                    let initialnum = await getLikeNumber()
                    likenum.innerHTML = initialnum
                }
                displayLikes()

                async function myFunction() {
                    localStorage.setItem('likebtn', !JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('likebtn')));
                    setLikeBtnColor();
                    if (likebtn.style.color === 'cornflowerblue') {
                        fetch('/postlikes/'+postName, {
                            method:"POST",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                removed_like: false,
                                liked_post:postName,
                                is_liked:true
                            }),
                            headers:{
                                "Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                            }
                        })
                        let currentLikeNum = await getLikeNumber();
                        likenum.innerHTML = currentLikeNum
                    } else {
                        fetch('/postlikes/'+postName, {
                            method:"POST",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                removed_like:true,
                                is_liked:false
                            }),
                            headers:{
                                "Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                            }
                        })
                        let currentLikeNum = await getLikeNumber();
                        likenum.innerHTML = currentLikeNum
                    }};
                likebtn.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
                
    
            </script>
```

This is the Image Table:

```
class Image(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title=db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    img_location = db.Column(db.String(600), nullable=False)
    mimetype = db.Column(db.String(10))
    post_name = db.Column(db.String(150),nullable=False, unique=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    manga_name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    reports = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    number_of_comments = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

(Yes, I am very well aware of the fact that I should be using multiple tables but I have specifically intended to use one table, for now.)

The app was made using flask.

Please help me.

Comment: what is this line supposed to do ?==>  post.likes = post.likes

Comment: @ScottC it is to set the new number of likes to the previous number of likes, as it was before the user liked the post.

Comment: It looks to me that you are setting `post.likes` to itself. ie. To the **current** value of post.likes. (which is essentially redundant).

Answer (score 1):

You add one like when the `button` that was clicked was a `button` with the color `'cornflowerblue'`. It should add one when the `button` was black. Change it.

```
async function myFunction() {
     .......
     if (likebtn.style.color === 'cornflowerblue') {
         ........
     }
     ........
}
```

to it

```
async function myFunction() {
     .........
      if (likebtn.style.color !== 'cornflowerblue') {
        .........
      }
     ........
}
```